# Finding length of cross product of two vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

Given $ v = (-2a\sin(2t),2a\cos(2t), 2a\cos(t) )$

and $k= (-4a\cos(2t),-4a\sin(2t),-2a\sin t)$

Finding $|v \times k|$. Now I am finding it hard to compute determinant. There must be an easy way because this question was of 3 points only in test I gave yesterday. Thanks for help

EDIT : This question is originally part of following question : Find the curvature and torsion at any point t of the curve $x=a\cos(2t) , y=a\sin(2t), z=2a\sin(t)$

Comment: Do you know how to take cross products? I suspect trigonometric identities will simplify the question a great deal

Comment: yeah i also suspected that. But its becoming complex

Comment: Okay, I used Mathematica and the result is complicated and does not simplify much.

Comment: check the edit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v\cdot k=-4a^2\sin t\cos t$, $|v|^2=4a^2(1+\cos^2 t)=4a^2(2-\sin^2 t)$ and $|k|^2=4a^2(4+\sin^2 t)$, we can use [an identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Alternative_formulation)

$$|v\times k|^2=|v|^2|k|^2-(v\cdot k)^2\\=16a^4(8-2\sin^2 t-\sin^4 t-\sin^2t(1-\sin^2 t))\\=16a^4(8-3\sin^2 t).$$

Comment: What formula are you using ?

Comment: But how to find $|v \times k|$

Comment: @Gathdi Take the square root of the last expression, obviously.

Comment: $\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}\newcommand{\na}{\left\| \a\right\|}\newcommand{\nb}{\left\| \b\right\|}$@Gathdi Use the formula $$\boxed{\left\| \a \times \b \right\|^2 = \na ^2\nb ^2 -(\a\cdot \b)^2}.$$ This formula can help you find the squared length of the cross product of two vectors without needing to compute the actual cross product. To see why this formula is true, recall that $\color{teal}{\a \cdot \b = \na \nb \cos\theta} $ and $\color{teal}{\left\|\a \times \b \right\| = \na  \nb \sin\theta} $, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\a$ and $\b$.